# AuthorizeAttribute, constructors, and stopping dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this (simplified) controller setup:

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute]
public class MainController : Controller {}

public class AccountController : MainController 
{
    private IService _iService;

    public AccountController() 
    {
        _service = DependencyFactory.Resolve<IService>(SessionManager.ServiceKey)
    }
    public AccountController(IService service) 
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

And `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` looks something like:

```
public CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool serviceKeyIsGood = CheckServiceKey(SessionManager.ServiceKey);
        return serviceKeyIsGood;
    }
}
```

The goal is to only have the account controller run if the user is authenticated, as defined by the presence of a "good" service key.

The problem I'm having is that the constructor for `AccountController` runs before OnAuthorize runs which causes the service to blow up (by design) since its service key is bad.

What's the best way to manage this?  I'd like to take advantage of the simplicity of the CustomAuthorizeAttribute, and I have to avoid re-architecting the way our services are instantiated.  (And the dependency factory is necessary as MVC complains about now having parameterless constructors.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use injection of factorymethod instead of service itself:

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute]
public class MainController : Controller

public class AccountController : MainController 
{
    private Func<IService> _serviceFactory;

    public AccountController() 
    {
        _serviceFactory= DependencyFactory.Resolve<Func<IService>>(SessionManager.ServiceKey)
    }
    public AccountController(Func<IService> serviceFactory) 
    {
        _serviceFactory= serviceFactory;
    }
}
```

and use: to get service: `service = _serviceFactory()` when you need it.

PS: I recommend you to use standard methods for DI in MVC (controller factory or internal dependency resolver) to avoid code such `_serviceFactory= DependencyFactory.Resolve<Func<IService>>(SessionManager.ServiceKey)`

Comment: I agree that DI is the way to go, but for some reason MVC does not like having parameterless constructors.  (I've had a hard time pin-pointing why...Unity resolution should take of the issue for us, but it's not for some reason...that's a separate SO post.)  Having the parameterless constructor satisfies MVC's complaining, while having the DI constructor allows for testing.  The service factory is an interesting approach, but we'd have to rewire our Unity container.  We've ended up just swallowing resolution errors that are failing for security reasons since the user is kicked out anyway.

Comment: Unity container can resolve Func<T> out from the box if you register T in container